# using mapstruct with service

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the following Mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",
    nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.IGNORE)
public interface StudentMapper {

    StudentMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper( StudentMapper.class );

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    Student map(Map<String, Object> map, @MappingTarget Student student);

}
```

This is my StudentService which uses the MAPPER:

```
import static com.test.StudentMapper.MAPPER;

public class StudentService {
    public void update(final @Valid Map<String, Object> map, Student student) { 
        Student result = MAPPER.map(map, student);
    }
}
```

When I run my tests:

I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke map(Object) because "this.qualifier" is null`

How can I inject Qualifier properly when I use the mapper in my StudentService class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using

```
componentModel = "spring"
```

i would suggest that you simply inject the mappers like normal dependencies via dependency injection.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StudentService {

    private final StudentMapper studentMapper;

    public void update(final @Valid Map<String, Object> map, Student student) { 
        Student result = MAPPER.updateStudentFromMap(map, student);
    }
}
```

I am not sure the code you provided is a viable way to use mapstruct.

```
public interface StudentMapper {

StudentMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper( StudentMapper.class );
```